# Windows 95 - desktop larger than screen resolution

Tags: windows, windows-95

I remember using a computer with Windows installed, and it had not one, but **two** resolution settings in Display Properties - one for the screen, the other for the desktop itself, and if the desktop resolution was larger than screen's, you could use the mouse to move the display.

Was it a standard feature on some build of Windows 95, or was it just some external addon?

Comment: If I recall correctly, this happens when you set the resolution to bigger than the screens resolution. Most likely an ATI or nVidia driver feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this depends on graphic card drivers. 
ATI had this, if I remember.

Answer (score 3):

I can't recall any version of Windows offering this option. However [this](https://superuser.com/questions/15140/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-display-resolution-higher-than-the-max) question covers the topic with links to Virtual Desktop software that will provide this ability.

Answer (score 1):

This was a feature of windows 95, supported by drivers, one example was ATI.

This was blocked by Microsoft in windows 98, in order to make users buying more big monitors.

Partly restored in windows XP.