# Windows XP Increase screen resolution beyond maximum

Tags: windows-xp, resolution

My Windows XP computer uses a `1440px` by `900px` monitor. I find myself wishing it was bigger... but is there a way to set the screen resolution to larger than `1440`by`900`?

Comment: Attach a different screen.

Comment: I don't have another screen... nor enough to buy one at the moment

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/15140/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-display-resolution-higher-than-the-max

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could look into [virtual desktops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presuming your graphics card can support higher resolutions than your monitor can support you can increase the desktop size and have to scroll around your desktop. This is not advisable IMHO but if you want to try:

Go to `Display Settings`. Then click on `Advanced Settings`. Under `Monitor` uncheck `Hide modes that this monitor Cannot Display`
or
Under `Adapter` Click on `list all modes`

Then simply choose one larger than your monitor supports and give it a go.
However be warned some monitors will simply display a mgs saying input is out of range.

Hope it helps/