# Making a 26" LCD into bigger resolution

Tags: display, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to use a display resolution higher than the max?](https://superuser.com/questions/15140/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-display-resolution-higher-than-the-max)

I recently got a 26" HDTV LCD as a gift. I am using it primarily for my PC. The highest it will go is 1366x768. I was wondering if I could make it go higher? I mean there's no reason it shouldn't since it's 26". At least, it should be well over 1900x1200....

Comment: well, the question is a well-formed question, there is no exact duplicate, it's constructive, it is asking for a solution. the problem is just that it's kind of impossible...

Comment: I can't understand the downvotes. I know it's a silly question, but people don't born knowing everything.

Comment: @jahkr "HD" can mean 720p, which is what 1366x768 is equivalent to.

Answer (score 8):

The resolution of the monitor has nothing to do with its size.  LCD monitors consist of discrete pixels, the number of which determine the resolution.  Your monitor is 1366 pixels wide by 768 pixels tall, so that's the maximum resolution it can display.

Comment: I feel a reversal coming....

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary factors that determine the maximum resolution you can select.

1. The maximum resolution of your monitor.
2. The maximum resolution of your video card (and possibly the version of the drivers installed.)

You'll need to specify the make and model numbers of each in order to determine the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you got so called "HD Ready" lcd TV which have their native resolution 1366x768 pixels - that means, the screen does not have more physical pixels then those 1366x768. If you had "Full HD" TV you could use 1920x1080 pixels and standard PC displays sometimes offer even more.

So in my opinion, this is absolutely impossible.