# Get a higher resolution on a remote Window-7 machine (via VNC)

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution, vnc

I'm building a Windows 7 machine to be operated headlessly with VNC.  I want to set the resolution to match the monitor that will be used (at 1680x1050) instead of the resolution of the monitor temporarily attached for building (at 1366x768).  It won't let me do it with the currently installed monitor.  Is there some way of doing this, perhaps by installing another monitor driver?  I'm using the native Sandy Bridge graphics on an Asus P8Z68-V Pro mobo.

Comment: In the main interface there are 2 things "hide modes this monitor cant display" and "list all modes" . When in Display resolution, double click on the graphic pic of the monitor, and you will find those buttons. I doubt it will help, but it is there.

Comment: Perhaps related/usable: [Is there any way to use a display resolution higher than the max?](http://superuser.com/questions/15140/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-display-resolution-higher-than-the-max)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by simply unplugging the monitor from the remote PC, then you can set the resolution to whatever you want (I assume this is acceptable as you indicated "headless setup"). However if you are currently at remote location you can disable the monitor in device manager and then reboot. This only works if your VNC application runs as a service and allows prelogin access like Teamviewer or if your computer boots right to the windows desktop and the VNC host is in the start up folder.

Comment: How to set resolution to custom values? I get only 640x480 (in teamviewer) when I unplug my monior.