# Windows 10 - Use a screen resolution that's higher than what my monitor supports?

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I need to be able to see what an application looks like in a variety of screen resolutions, particularly resolutions that are lot larger than what my monitor can support. It doesn't look like Windows offers this ability? On Linux you can use xrandr to set any resolution you like, you then have to pan but at least it has the option.

I've looked at historic posts on this and it looks like a virtual desktop was a solution that's no longer available.

Without having to buy a monitor that's capable of the resolutions that I'm looking to test in, is there any alternative solution out there, specifically for Windows 10?

Comment: You can use a virtual desktop application:  https://superuser.com/questions/15140/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-display-resolution-higher-than-the-max

Answer (score 0):

Try the free
[Custom Resolution Utility (CRU)](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU):

> Custom Resolution Utility (CRU) is an EDID editor that focuses on custom resolutions. CRU shows you how the monitor defines resolutions and other capabilities and gives you the power to change it. Add custom resolutions, remove unwanted resolutions, edit FreeSync ranges, and more. CRU creates software EDID overrides in the registry and does not modify the hardware.

The currently most recent version is from January 2021,
so should work on Windows 10.